# Working with time series GDP data

Tags: plotting, import, time-series

I have two questions.

First, how do I get a list of points from `CountryData["UnitedStates", {{"GDP"}, {1960, 2018}}]` as opposed to a graph.

Second, if I have a some data in CSV format with dates (in the form --/--/----) in one column, how do I get Mathematica to understand, when I import the data, that it must plot dates? The other column contains GDP values.

I am a beginner. I know how to import data and use `ListPlot`.

Comment: `CountryData["UnitedStates", {{"GDP"}, {1960, 2018}}]["Path"]` gives pairs of {date, value}. If you have CSV file like 01/02/2000,10 etc., import that as `Import[file, "CSV"]`, then `MapAt[DateList[{#,{"Month","Day","Year"}}]&,imported_file,{All,1}]` and then `DateListPlot[%]`.

Comment: @Alx Thank you!